# OpenSSL PKCS12 to PEM conversion - output different for different versions

Tags: java, openssl

I found a difference in the output to PEM file that openssl generates with different versions.

I use following command to generate the PEM file

So for the same p12 file we get following output:

From version 0.9.8

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: alias
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 34 30 31 35 39 36 39 39 34 30 38 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: alias
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 34 30 31 35 39 36 39 39 34 30 38 
subject=/CN=HCP
issuer=/CN=HCP
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

from version 1.0.1g the output is following:

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: alias
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 34 30 31 35 39 36 39 39 34 30 38 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBSwIBADCCASwGByqGSM44BAEwggEfAoGBAP1/U4EddRIpUt9KnC7s5Of2EbdS
PO9EAMMeP4C2USZpRV1AIlH7WT2NWPq/xfW6MPbLm1Vs14E7gB00b/JmYLdrmVCl
pJ+f6AR7ECLCT7up1/63xhv4O1fnxqimFQ8E+4P208UewwI1VBNaFpEy9nXzrith
1yrv8iIDGZ3RSAHHAhUAl2BQjxUjC8yykrmCouuEC/BYHPUCgYEA9+GghdabPd7L
vKtcNrhXuXmUr7v6OuqC+VdMCz0HgmdRWVeOutRZT+ZxBxCBgLRJFnEj6EwoFhO3
zwkyjMim4TwWeotUfI0o4KOuHiuzpnWRbqN/C/ohNWLx+2J6ASQ7zKTxvqhRkImo
g9/hWuWfBpKLZl6Ae1UlZAFMO/7PSSoEFgIUTpb1TDZkcXUdiHLQvj0NRA3v0ss=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: alias
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 34 30 31 35 39 36 39 39 34 30 38 
subject=/CN=HCP
issuer=/CN=HCP
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So there is a difference in the private key.

Problem is that later we try to parse the private key from Java with following code:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
KeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(key));
keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

then the output of version 0.9.8 is not parsed and fails with InvalidKeySpec.

Was something changed in OpenSSL and how can we avoid this?

Comment: Is he **sure** he's using 1.0.2d? PEM `DSA PRIVATE KEY` is the **"legacy" format** (actually one of them) which is the default for some `openssl` commands including `pkcs12` in **0.9.8 and lower**; 1.0.0 and higher use `PRIVATE KEY` which is PKCS#8. It's very unlikely the developers would change back, the 1.0.2d CHANGES file doesn't suggest they did, and both a source build on my Linux and the ShiningLight package on my Windows produce `PRIVATE KEY` PKCS#8 format as expected. Have him re-check what version he's using, especially if he has more than one present on his system.

Comment: PS if he or anyone does need to use 0.9.8 or earlier, use `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt` to convert any of the legacy private key formats to PKCS#8 unencrypted, which Java finds much more palatable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'll have to check about the version that produces the "BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY" formatted pem file.

Comment: I can confirm that actually it was 0.9.8 producing the "DSA PRIVATE KEY" version. Thanks for the hint. I'll update the question

Comment: It would appear that I newer version they changed the default back to DSA PRIVATE KEY.